# Work two methods in seperate threads simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to run two methods in parallel. To do that I have written a code like below:

After getting critiques, I thought I should be clearer. `method1()` is a local method which runs on my local computer. `method2()` is a web method which sends some data to a remote computer to process and return result. Since the work takes too long I divide the data into 2 pieces and one part is processed on local and the other one is on remote.

After the jobs finishes I combine the results.

```
//str1 and str2 are defined outside the main method.

Thread[] threads = new Thread[2];

threads[0] = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() { str1 = method1(); }
};


threads[1] = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() { str2 = method2(); }
};

    threads[0].start();
    threads[1].start();
```

I get null from `method2()` in return when I try this way. Bu if I run `method2()` outside thread definition str2 is `null`.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() { str1 = method1(); }
};

thread.start();

str2 = method2();
```

`method2()` returns what it should return. The explanation could be that `thread[1].start()` does not start.

Comment: Assuming you've tested it, what are your results?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it.

Comment: You asked an answer.

Comment: @zkanoca You might want to review that question. I'm not able to follow, where the code is not behaving as you expect. Where do you wait for the thread to finish before checking it's result?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work for what you explained what you want to do. (Before your edit ...)

Nevertheless, let me suggest using one of Java's [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). They may be of great use to you when it comes to extending the functionality or adding more tasks ...

After your edit:
I suspect a "racing condition". That is: You check for the result, before the thread has finished and set the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself the question, why would you like to run two methods parallel?

when working with threads always think in terms of task(work to be done) and the executor of the task(which is a thread in this case).

So if we say that the stuff which goes inside a method is a task, which we need to perform, then the next question is who will accomplish that task.

Now in your case you have two methods to run which means two tasks at hand.
Next question is are these tasks mutually exclusive? if yes then the method you adopted above is right.

If the tasks are not mutually exclusive and depend on a common state. Like below:-

```
//x and y are state variables which are shared across two tasks(method1 and method2) 
 int x; int y;

 method1(){x++;y--;}
 method2(){x--;y++;}

 Thread[] threads = new Thread[2];

threads[0] = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() { method1(); }
};


threads[1] = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() { method2(); }
};

    threads[0].start();
    threads[1].start();
```

Now, Here we have to make sure that the two threads have sequential access to the state variables x and y . So we do that by synchronizing access to these state variables by using thread synchronization techniques.

There are various approaches to that, the simplest being adding the synchronized keyword to method1 and method 2 as follows:-

```
 synchronized method1(){x++;y--;}
 synchronized method2(){x--;y++;}
```

rest remains same. For reference you can see various thread synchronization approaches for a more efficient approach.